# Natbib bibliography style with relatively short referencing (MNRAS Style?)

Tags: natbib

I'm looking for a `natbib` bibliography style with relatively short referencing in the bibliography.

Something that looks along the lines of the Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society (MNRAS) or the Astrophysical Journal style. I can't seem to use these styles without adopting the full templates so I was hoping someone could recommend a similar style within `natbib`?

It would also need to cite by author and year in the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be a bit more specific as to what you mean by "relatively short referencing".

Comment: So an example from MNRAS:  Mead J. M. G., King L. J., Sijacki D., Leonard A., Puchwein E., McCarthy I. G., 2010, MNRAS, 406, 434                                                                                
so it gives the names of the first two or three authors with the year, the publication, the issue and the page numbers

Comment: Any suggestions at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> [a bibliography style] that looks along the lines of the Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society (MNRAS) or the Astrophysical Journal style. *I can't seem to use these styles without adopting the full templates* ... [emphasis added]

Are you sure about this claim? AFAICT, the `mnras` bibliography style appears to work just fine without loading the `mnras` document class -- at least as long as the `natbib` package is loaded with the option `longnamesfirst`. (The `mnras` citation style requires showing the names of all authors the first time a piece is cited; thereafter, truncated citation call-outs are to be used for pieces with more than 2 authors. That's why you should specify the `longnamesfirst` option.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc,
  author  = "Anna Maria Andretti and Brenda Michelle 
             Bugatti and Carla Martina Chevrolet",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3001,
  volume  = 1,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = "3--4",
}
@misc{def,
  author  = "Daniela Drabkin and Emmanuela Erickson and 
             Francesca Falcone",
  title   = "Further Thoughts",
  year    = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
% 'mnras' requires showing all authors the first time
% a piece is cited; truncated author list thereafter
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}

\begin{document}
\citep{abc}, \citet{abc}

\citet{def}, \citep{def}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You! I wasn't aware that this was the issue. Much appreciated