# Shortening citation call-outs to first-author-et-al in natbib (MNRAS syle)

Tags: citing, natbib, author-number

I'm using the natbib package with the MNRAS bibliography style, and I'm wondering how I can possibly have it so the citations within my article give one, or two authors, followed by `et al` rather than listing them all. I understand from reading similar questions it depends slightly on the bibliography style used.

When I was previously using the full MNRAS template this was done automatically, however when I use this bibliography style within my own template it gives multiple authors which clutters the text.

Apologies if this is a trivial question, I'm pretty novice.

Here are the lines from my file relating to the bibliography for reference:

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}

\bibliography{Mendeley.bib}
```

Comment: Have you tried omitting the option `longnamesfirst`?

Comment: Incidentally, one should *not* specify the filename extension in the argument of `\bibliography` -- it's understood that the extension should be (has to be?) `.bib`. This is a limitation of BibTeX; the newer `biblatex` package lets you specify bibliography files with extensions other than `.bib`.

Comment: If I remove the longnamesfirst option the MNRAS bibliography style is no longer comparible with an article style doumnet as far as i am aware.

Comment: I was advised to include this option as a way to actually use the MNRAS bibliography style without adopting the whole template, in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427108/natbib-bibliography-style-with-relatively-short-referencing-mnras-style

Comment: By yourself actually I see!

Comment: Either you ditch the `longnamesfirst` option (to get the shortened citation call-outs), or you abide by the style that says that the first time an entry is cited, all authors should be listed. You can’t have it both ways.